# How to change default navigation animation in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-development

Is there any way to change default navigation animation in react native. in IOS its swipe right to left. android bottom to top. can we make this constance for both platforms?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can set different modes for screens, one of them is `modal`:

```
const MainStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    SplashScreen: { screen: SplashScreen },
    OnBoardingScreen: { screen: OnBoarding },
    LoginScreen: { screen: LoginContainer },
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    },
    mode: "modal",
    cardStyle: { backgroundColor: "transparent" },
   transitionConfig: TransitionConfiguration,

  }
);
```

you can also use `transitionConfig`, it returns an object with two parameters `transitionSpec` and `screenInterpolator`. you can configure animation timing properties like duration and easing in the transitionSpec and layout transformations in screenInterpolator.
Here is an example:

```
    const TransitionConfiguration = () => {
  return {
    transitionSpec: {
      duration: 750,
      easing: Easing.out(Easing.poly(4)),
      timing: Animated.timing,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    },
    screenInterpolator: (sceneProps) => {
      const { layout, position, scene } = sceneProps;
      const width = layout.initWidth;
      const { index, route } = scene
      const params = route.params || {}; // <- That's new
      const transition = params.transition || 'default'; // <- That's new
      return {
        collapseExpand: CollapseExpand(index, position),
        default: SlideFromRight(index, position, width),
      }[transition];
    },
  }
}
```

By default, new screens slides from right.

```
let SlideFromRight = (index, position, width) => {
  const inputRange = [index - 1, index, index + 1];
  const translateX = position.interpolate({
    inputRange: [index - 1, index, index + 1],
    outputRange: [width, 0, 0]
  })
  const slideFromRight = { transform: [{ translateX }] }
  return slideFromRight
};
```

There’s nothing too special about `transitionSpec`. In fact, it looks a lot like a standard React Native Animated example. We set the duration of our transition and the easing profile, configure it to be a timing-based animation rather than a spring, and to use the native driver for performance.

The screenInterpolator is where the magic happens. screenInterpolator is a function that React Navigation calls with an argument we’ll call sceneProps. screenInterpolator(sceneProps) is called for each screen in the stack and the return value is used to configure its transition.

If navigation(scene) has a param { transition : 'collapseExpand' } screen interpolator take’s CollapseExpand animation.

```
let CollapseExpand = (index, position) => {
  const inputRange = [index - 1, index, index + 1];
  const opacity = position.interpolate({
    inputRange,
    outputRange: [0, 1, 1],
  });

  const scaleY = position.interpolate({
    inputRange,
    outputRange: ([0, 1, 1]),
  });

  return {
    opacity,
    transform: [
      { scaleY }
    ]
  };
};
```

Comment: I have updated the comment. Please see that if that can be helpful.

Comment: I see, thing is in my project there are 100+ screens, it seems I need to do add custom code for every screen. and I think doing this kind of thing not gonna help for my reason. if its a less number of screen's project this will suit. Do you have any suggestion for my case?

Comment: There can be one workaround for your case: you can get routeName from sceneProps from transitionConfig and you can apply config conditionally for  those routes only.
eg:
transitionConfig: sceneProps => ({
    transitionSpec: sceneProps.scene.route.routeName === 'Screen2' ? screen2Config : {},
screenInterpolator: ... })